# Integers being multiplied by the wrong number

Tags: python, integer

I am trying to multiply some of the values of an array by 3, but when I print the array with its new values I see that the numbers have actually been multiplied by 2187 and not 3. Very strange.

```
for digit in digits:
    digits[0] = digits[0]*3
    digits[2] = digits[2]*3
    digits[4] = digits[4]*3
    digits[6] = digits[6]*3
```

The original numbers in the array are `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

What they should be after being multiplied is:

```
[3,2,9,4,15,6,21]
```

Instead we get `[2187,2,6561,4,10935,6,15309]`.

Comment: What happens exactly in your case, is that you are going through the loop once for each digit in the list. You have 7 digits in your list, so your multiplications get processed 7 times each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are multiplying it everytime and hence the large numbers! The loop multiplies the values each time by `3`.

Thus `1` will become `2187` which is `1*3*3*3*3*3*3*3`

- Either do it all at once (Remove the for loop)

  ```
  >>> digits =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  >>> digits[0] = digits[0]*3
  >>> digits[2] = digits[2]*3
  >>> digits[4] = digits[4]*3
  >>> digits[6] = digits[6]*3
  >>> digits
  [3, 2, 9, 4, 15, 6, 21]
  ```
- Or use a condition in the loop

  ```
  >>> digits =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  >>> for i, v in enumerate(digits):
  ...     if(i % 2 == 0):
  ...         digits[i] = v * 3
  ... 
  >>> digits
  [3, 2, 9, 4, 15, 6, 21]
  ```

  Here I have used `enumerate` which will return a tuple of index and values.
- Or you can even use a range function with a step of 2

  ```
  >>> digits =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  >>> for i in range(0, len(digits), 2):
  ...      digits[i] = digits[i]*3
  ... 
  >>> digits
  [3, 2, 9, 4, 15, 6, 21]
  ```

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate`? Why not just `for i in range(0, len(digits), 2)`?

Comment: @Paul Cheers added. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just to demonstrate Python slicing and list comprehensions:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> L[::2] = [x*3 for x in L[::2]]
>>> L
[3, 2, 9, 4, 15, 6, 21]
```

Select for replacement every other character with `L[::2] =`, then use a list comprehension to triple each of those entries in the list.